# Probability: ATM Random Security Code Computer Generation.

Tags: probability, permutations

In order to access one's bank account using an ATM, the user must key in a set of
numbers making up a security code; a code can be anything from a 1-digit to a 5-
digit number. This code is randomly assigned by the bank's computer. What is the
probability that the code supplied is a number that is greater than 300?

Since order is important, I thought of this problem as a permutations problem. My approach was to calculate the probability that a code generated is 300 or less, then subtracting this from one to get the probability requested. For the code to be 300 or less, _ _ 3 10 10. Here I am saying there is 1 way to fill up the first and second positions of the random code for this case, and that's by filling them with zeros. The third can only be filled in three ways (either a 1, 2, or 3). The fourth can be filled in 10 ways (including zero), and so is the case of the fifth (since we're not explicitly told that repeating of numbers is not allowed). The other possibility is that we can generate a two digit number. So _ _ _1 10. The fourth can only be filled by nine different numbers (excluding zero, as having a zero here will create an identical code for the next case). The fifth can be filled 10 different was (0 through to 9). Finally, the last possibility, _ _ _ _ 10.

To compute the sample space I said 10*10*10*10*10 + 10*10*10*10 +10*10*10 +9*10 +10 = 111100. The number of ways in which the event can happen is 400 ways. But when I then divide 111100 by 400 then subtract it from 1, I get the wrong answer. The solution to this problem is 0.9909. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is the key a number or a string?  Is 00120  a valid key?  Are 123 and 00123 different keys?

Comment: Its a number. And yes, 00120 is a valid key as its a valid five digit number. The zeros in front of the 120 are not negligible since since this is a security code.

Comment: So 01, 001, 0001, and 00001 are all the same number but different keys?

Comment: Yes, in this context, 123 and 00123 have to be different keys. If a person is given a five digit security code that's 00123, they cannot type in 123 at the ATM and expect the ATM to grant them access.

Comment: Yes sir, that's exactly the case (note: this is my interpretation of the problem, I could very well be wrong, but it seems very logical to me).

Answer (score 1):

***Under your assumptions***:

You need to treat 5 cases separately:

There are $10$ single digit keys ($0...9$);  ***none*** evaluate to a number greater than $300$

There are $100$ two digit keys ($00...99$);  ***none*** evaluate to a number greater than $300$.

There are $1000$ three digit keys ($000...999$); $301$ $(000...300)$ evaluate to a number less than or equal to $300$, so ***699*** evaluate to a number greater than $300$

There are $10000$ four digit keys ($0000...9999$); $301$ $(0000...0300)$ evaluate to a number less than or equal to $300$, so ***9699*** evaluate to a number greater than $300$

There are $100000$ five digit keys ($00000...99999$); $301$ $(00000...00300)$ evaluate to a number less than or equal to $300$, so ***99699*** evaluate to a number greater than $300$

Find the two sums and divide...

Comment: Thank you so much man! I actually got the exact answer to this problem just before you posted you solution to it for me. And it was a ll thanks to the question you asked me (whether or not 00123 and 123 are the same security codes). To find out the total number of ways the computer can arrange a five digit code, I said 10*10*10*10*10 = 100000. With the same reasoning, I got the total number of ways to create different four, three, two, and digit codes as 10000, 1000, 100, and 10. I added all five of these values to define my sample space.

Comment: To define the event that a three digit code that is less that 300 is selected, I got 1010 different ways. Then added the three different ways in which a three digit code equal to 300 can be generated (00300, 0300, and 300), to get a total number of ways in which the event A (event that the code generated is less than or equal to 300.) Then the probability of A happening is: P(A) = n(A)/n(S) = 1013/111110. Then the probability of event, say B (event that the code generated is greater than 300), happening is = 1-(1013)/(111110) = 0.9909.